# Replace a string with another string in all files below my current dir

Tags: string, bash, sed

How do I replace every occurrence of a string with another string below my current directory?

**Example:** I want to replace every occurrence of `www.fubar.com` with `www.fubar.ftw.com` in every file under my current directory.

From research so far I have come up with

```
sed -i 's/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com/g' *.php
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Comment: For any idiots like me, the `/g` at the end is important

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You're on the right track, use `find` to locate the files, then `sed` to edit them, for example:

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i -e 's/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com/g' {} \;
```

Notes

- The `.` means current directory - i.e. in this case, search in and below the current directory.
- For some versions of `sed` you need to specify an extension for the `-i` option, which is used for backup files.
- The `-exec` option is followed by the command to be applied to the files found, and is terminated by a semicolon, which must be escaped, otherwise the shell consumes it before it is passed to find.

Comment: I strongly suggest to use `-i.bak` in sed. Anyhow, this is great solution. +1

Comment: @Michal what is the .bak for? Anyone, what exactly does the {} \ mean at the end of your statement?

Comment: @martin How do I escape single quotes and double quotes in the sed statement?

Comment: @KRB: .bak is for backup in case you change something you didn't want to change. `{}` is substituted by find command with file name when executing a command by `-exec`.

Comment: @KRB: The `\;` is to pass `;` to the find command (without '\' bash will interpret it and not pass it as an argument). find expects `;`  somewhere after '-exec' to know which arguments are for `find` it self  and which are for called command.

Comment: @KRB: in regex's the letters after last slash are options. Here '/g' stands for "do global" substitutions (all in a line, not only first).

Comment: @KRB - you should be able to escape quotes in the usual shell way.  It gets tricky when you have a mixture of single and double quotes.  But you may want yo use double quotes around the "s///".  Then you can escape single \' and double \" quotes within that sed command.

Comment: On OSX, sed requires an explicit argument for the in-place suffix, so you need to do `sed -i '' 's/...`

Comment: @RockyMM - it's a placeholder for the "found file", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607542/why-does-find-exec-mv-target-not-work-on-cygwin

Comment: If you add an -e before the 's/www' it also becomes compatible with non GNU sed (e.g. OS X)

Answer (score 4):

A more efficient ***** alternative to the currently accepted [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7450348/5293284):

```
grep "www.fubar.com" . -lr | xargs sed -i 's/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com/g'
```

This avoids the inefficiency of the `find . -exec` method, which needlessly runs a `sed` in-place replacement over all files below your current directory regardless of if they contain the string you're looking for or not, by instead using `grep -lr`. This gets just the files containing the string you want to replace which you can then pipe to `xargs sed -i` to perform the in-place replacement on just those files.

---

*** :** I used `time` to make a cursory comparison of my method with the accepted solution (adapted for my own use case); The `find . -exec`-style method took **3.624s** to run on my machine and my above proposed solution took **0.156s**, so roughly 23x faster for my use case.

Answer (score 3):

Solution using find, args and sed:

```
find . -name '*.php' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com/g'
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and the selected answer @johnny

Comment: It uses one process more, but represents a more general pattern which is very useful in its own right; i.e. generate-args | xargs command

Comment: xargs builds a command line and tries to run the command after as few times as possible, exec runs the command once for every file. -print0 and -0 takes care of filenames with spaces in them.

Comment: I think this is a good solution when running in a Windows environment where file names and folder names may have space characters in them.  I find myself constantly having to use the `-print0 | xargs -r0` arg combo.

Comment: The suggested solution worked great. Except for one gotcha: It replaces symlinks with a file of the target's contents.

Answer (score 2):

A pure bash solution

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.php
do
    while read -r line
    do
       echo "${line/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com}"
    done < "$file" > tempo && mv tempo "$file"

done
```

Comment: The OP wanted directory recursion. It's certainly not hard to add to this script.

Comment: yes definitely not hard with a call  to globstar and double asterix

Answer (score 0):

If there are no subfolders, a simpler to remember way is

```
replace "www.fubar.com" "www.fubar.ftw.com" -- *
```

where * can also be a list of files

from the manual:

> Invoke replace in one of the following ways:
>
> ```
>        shell> replace from to [from to] ... -- file_name [file_name] ...
>        shell> replace from to [from to] ... < file_name
> ```

If you have hidden files with a dot you can add those to `*` with

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

If you only have **one depth of subfolders** you can use `*/*` instead of `*`

```
replace "www.fubar.com" "www.fubar.ftw.com" -- */*
```

Answer (score 0):

When using **ZSH** as your shell you can do:

```
sed -i 's/www.fubar.com/www.fubar.ftw.com/g' **/*.php
```