# find -exec mv tells me No such file or directory

Tags: unix, find, mkdir, mv

if I run:

`mkdir -p "$HOME"/old_foo && find "$HOME" -type d -name "*foo" -exec mv -vi {} "$HOME"/new_foo \;`

I get:

`/Users/medialab/old_foo -> /Users/medialab/new_foo`

but also:

`find: /Users/medialab/old_foo: No such file or directory`

why is `find` searching for the directory old_foo after it already moved it?

Comment: the message is an annoyance, but the real problem for me is the non-zero return code of `1` which messes things up for me.

Answer (score 4):

For your question, I think that `find` try to match the pattern also inside the directory.
When `find` try to enter inside the directory, the directory is not here because he is already moved.

You can see it that if you use :

```
find "$HOME" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*foo" -exec mv -vi {} "$HOME"/new_foo \;
```

The command force the `find` to  stay in your repertory, and don't explore inside all your repertory.

Answer (score 3):

This seems similar to the question here : [Why does find -exec mv {} ./target/ + not work ? (on cygwin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607542/why-does-find-exec-mv-target-not-work-on-cygwin)

As pointed by the author, you could use gnu mv

I personally prefer using xargs as shown below :

```
mkdir old_foo && find . -type d -name "*foo" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} new_foo
```