# How to pipeline in a line by line fashion in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sh, pipeline

For example, I have a code can find me the directory name in the current folder without . in the front:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '\./[^.]*$'
```

However, it gives me

```
./Templates
./eclipse-workspace
./Public
./Documents
./VirtualBox VMs
./Videos
./CLionProjects
./jd2
```

I need to do

```
du -sh
```

for each line of them sequentially, how can I do?

Comment: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '\./[^.]*$' -exec du -sh '{}' +`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is a -exec command built into **find**, it is difficult to use (see [Why does find -exec mv {} ./target/ + not work ? (on cygwin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607542/why-does-find-exec-mv-target-not-work-on-cygwin)).

What you are looking for is this pipe command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -regex '\./[^.]*$' | cut -c 3-
```

Anytime the **find** command output something, the **cut**s happen.